# I want to get value from my json by field name

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

I'm working with this json data, but the problem is that I want to get one of the field "sz_price" from this list. I found code from the internet that's supposed to be valid for this action but I still don't understand the method to get a single value.
I don't want to use any loop, I just have a single field I want.

```
{"label":"4mm","sz_stock":"","sz_price":"50","sz_id":"6","count":1}]

$.getJSON("check.php", function(result){
            $.each(result, function(i, field){
                $("div").append(field + " ");
            });
        });
```

Comment: Try `result.sz_price`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use this instead the loop:

```
$("div").append(result["sz_price"]);
```

Comment: thanks sir this is my actual code now
`function check_sizes(id){ 

    $.getJSON("get_size.php?szz="+id, function(result){
   var ch = result["sz_price"]
  
       var ch = $("#price").val(result["sz_price"]);
      
        });}`
But this not also working if i check the value in alert() it shows "undefined"

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `each`, just use `result.label`, or `result.sz_stock`, or `result.sz_prize`, etc.

Comment: thanks sir this is my actual code now 

function check_sizes(id){ $.getJSON("get_size.php?szz="+id, function(result){ var ch = result["sz_price"] var ch = $("#price").val(result["sz_price"]); });}

 But this not also working if i check the value in alert() it shows "undefined"

Comment: did you try `result.label` ?

Comment: you can use Chrome or Firefox debugger and put a break point to `var ch = result["sz_price"];` line, and then see if you have a value `result`

Comment: ThankS Alot Thanks Thanks .. Its Done Thanks for Responding

Comment: what was the solution then?

Comment: this time the the problem was in json First my json was 
`[{"label":"4mm","sz_stock":"","sz_price":"50","sz_id":"6","count":1}]`
and Now I changed It To
`{"label":"4mm","sz_stock":"","sz_price":"50","sz_id":"6","count":1}`
Just Removed ` [  ] ` :)